# Dynamic Linq in abp.io 5.1 using EF Core in .NET 6 framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dynamic-linq, abp

I use a generated abp.io 5.1 application which uses EF Core accessing a MySQL database, running on the .NET 6 framework.

I already read those docs :

- https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Entity-Framework-Core
- https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Tutorials/part-7?UI=NG&DB=EF

I want to use dynamic linq.

I've installed this package : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq/6.2.18

One example I would use :

```
using (var context = new EntityContext())
{
    var query =  context.Customers
                        .Where("Orders.Count >= @0", 5)
                        .OrderBy("Orders.Count")
                        .ToList();
}
```

In my `TestAppService`, I would like to have a filter in a string

```
public async Task<int> GetCountAsync(string filter)
{
    var query =  context.Customers
                        .Where(filter)
                        .Count

    // ... other lines of code ...
}
```

I know the syntax is not OK.

Help me to implement that method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom repository like

```cs
public interface ICustomerRepository : IRepository<Customer, Guid>
{
    Task<int> GetCountAsync(string filter);
}
```

implement it on **EntityFrameworkCore** layer like:

```cs
public class CustomerRepository : EfCoreRepository<MyDbContext, Customer, Guid>, ICustomerRepository 
{
    public CustomerRepository(IDbContextProvider<TestAppDbContext> dbContextProvider) 
        : base(dbContextProvider)
    {

    }

    public async Task<int> GetCountAsync(string filter)
    {
        var dbContext = await GetDbContextAsync();
        return await dbContext.Set<Customer>()
            .Where(filter)
            .CountAsync();
    }
}
```

Check [ABP Custom Repository Implementation docs](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Repositories#custom-repositories) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct, see this corrected code-block:

```cs
public async Task<int> GetCountAsync(string filter)
{
    var count = context.Customers
                    .Where(filter)
                    .Count();

    // ... other lines of code ...
}
```

For more details on how to use System.Linq.Dynamic.Core or Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq, see https://dynamic-linq.net/.